# How do I get the private DNS for a CfnNetworkInterface?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I want to create a CNAME entry for an ENI which I will attach to an EC2 instance so that I can have a persistent internal DNS entry for the EC2 instance that will survive the instance being recreated (the ENI will just be attached to the new instance).

I am creating the ENI using CDK and [CfnNetworkInterface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/java/software/amazon/awscdk/services/ec2/CfnNetworkInterface.html). In the Console, when I manually create a network interface, I can see a property that looks like `ip-172-31-22-68.eu-west-2.compute.internal` labelled `Private DNS (IPv4)`: how do I access this value please?

Or should I be creating an A record that points to the IP address of the ENI, rather than a CNAME that points at the DNS of the ENI?

Comment: It appears that this class doesn't expose any attributes related to internal DNS. What you suggest might be the easiest workaround

Comment: I've tried `myEni.getPrivateIpAddress()` to get the IP address, but this resolves to undefined too. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing code, also `Cfn` resources aren't "stable" so I wouldn't be surprised if something isn't working as it should

Comment: Ah, found it. It was due to `getPrivateIpAddress()` representing the data passed during synth, not the resulting IP address after the object was created.  Using `getAttrPrimaryPrivateIpAddress()` is what I was after. Thanks for the prompt.